# How can I run a list of functions on an input?

Tags: kdb

```
q) ({2*x};{3*x})
```

How can I apply the list of functions to an input, e.g. 4, something like:

```
({2*x};{3*x})[4]
8 12
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use apply (`@`) each left (`\:`)

```
({2*x};{3*x})@\:4
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach to apply each left

```
q)({2*x};{3*x})[;4]
8 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to generalise Michaels answer, if your function takes more than one input/parameter then you'd need to use dot-apply (`.`) rather than `@`. Dot-apply would work in both cases using:

```
q)({2*x};{3*x}).\:(),4
8 12
q)({y+2*x};{y+3*x}).\:(),4 100
108 112
```